# Logback using springboot

Tags: logging, spring-boot, logback

Am trying to build small application using springboot where i am trying to use logback as my logger,i don't want to specify Maxfilesize in my logback-spring.xml,I want to read it from my properties file(application.yml).Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot doesn't offer a full autoconfiguration for logback yet as it does for other frameworks (probably, due to logback's flexibility and use case variety).

However, Spring Boot properties are set into a different range of scopes and one of them is the JVM system. As logback is also capable of reading properties from the system, you'll need to address it in your *logback-spring.xml* file:

```xml
<triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
  <maxFileSize>${logback.maxFileSize}</maxFileSize>
</triggeringPolicy>
```

Then, add it to your *application.yml* too:

```yml
logback:
    maxFileSize: 5MB
```

I haven't tested this code myself, while I've got several applications for which the log level property is passed this way.

**See also:**

- [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply..,It didn't work for me.as i can set a file path in  application.yml it works fine but maxFileSize and maxHistory is not working when i place those in application.yml

Comment: I'll take a look at it tomorrow @Sachin